# using google map variable in ajax callback

Tags: ajax, google-maps

Why map variable is not accessible in **ajax callback function (success)** while other variables are.

For further explanation of my problem I have added the comments in my following code

```
var map;
var g = 10;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_el'), mapOptions);
    g = 15;
    alert(g); // Gives 15
    alert(map.getCenter()); // Gives correct values
}
```

But in below function in ajax callback request. I face wired response

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    initialize();            
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.aspx/getLocation',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(g); // Gives 15
            alert(map.getCenter()); // Gives error => map is undefined
        }
    });
});
```

**Note :** Both above functions are in the same scope in a script tag

Comment: Just to confirm.. the error is that map is undefined?

Comment: Yes. that is the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `initialize` function is executing **`asynchronously`**.  So try to do the ajax call with a small time lag using **`setTimeout()`** like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialize();            
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.aspx/getLocation',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(g); // Gives 15
                alert(map.getCenter()); // Gives error => map is undefined
            }
        });
    }, 10);
});
```

or with **`callbacks`**.